# Are there continuous relaxations of the notion of function composition (e.g. for automorphisms)?

Tags: automorphism-group, relaxations

An automorphism can be applied any integer number of times.  Is there a sensible notion of applying it a *non*-integer number of times?

I have the same question for more general types of transformations.

EtA:
I'm curious about the most general version of this question, but the motivating example is automorphisms of real or complex vector spaces.

EtA(x2-3):
An example would be (for the reals): $f(x) = 2x$, $f^n(x) = 2^nx$.  On the other hand, if $f(x) = -x$, then we can still define $f^n(x) = (-1)^nx$, but this can take complex values.

Comment: Automorphisms of what? I think this would very much depend on the type of object.

Comment: Also, why/in what context do you want this?

Comment: see edits, and this related question I just posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4051430/fractional-power-of-a-linear-operator